# checkboxSelection in ag grid not functioning

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am not getting selection checkbox in ag grid.I have follwed everything as per documentaion.Below is my code.Please help we with the issue.

html

```
<ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"

    rowSelection='multiple'
    [modules]="modules"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

TS

```
export class TailComponent {
  rowSelection = 'multiple';
  modules = [ClientSideRowModelModule];
  columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make',checkboxSelection: true },
    {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model' },
    {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'}
];

rowData = [
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 }
];
}
```

Comment: why is rowSelection not enclosed in  [ ..]. in html is it a typo?

Comment: @pratik Nope.I am defining it to be multiple at that point itself.

Comment: well thats the issue. it should be [rowSelection] in html

Comment: @pratik Still its not working